# BTRFS partition auto mounts ro

Tags: partition, btrfs, read-only

i have my `/home/` on a btrfs partition and it appears like  after loggingf in to Plasma with my default userm, it becomes mounted `ro` (`rw` after boot before login). I booted a USB live system asnd ran `btrfs check` but that didnot appear to fix the issue:

```
$ sudo btrfs check /dev/sdb1
Opening filesystem to check...
Checking filesystem on /dev/sdb1
UUID: ba093e47-a5d2-4753-b39e-64413066d9c8
[1/7] checking root items
[2/7] checking extents
[3/7] checking free space cache
[4/7] checking fs roots
[5/7] checking only csums items (without verifying data)
[6/7] checking root refs
[7/7] checking quota groups skipped (not enabled on this FS)
found 890685730816 bytes used, no error found
total csum bytes: 865299716
total tree bytes: 3958702080
total fs tree bytes: 2745729024
total extent tree bytes: 193478656
btree space waste bytes: 706285981
file data blocks allocated: 2916973436928
 referenced 946788216832
```

I then created a new user and it appears like I can login with it and my partitiopn remains mounted `rw` but when I try to copy a certain dir from my original user account, I get the following:

```
$ journalctl -f | grep -i btrfs
Aug 10 21:33:11 DesktopRon kernel: BTRFS error (device sdb1): tree first key mismatch detected, bytenr=874068066304 parent_transid=2042756 key expected=(574193057792,137,0) has=(574193057792,169,0)
Aug 10 21:33:11 DesktopRon kernel: BTRFS: error (device sdb1: state A) in __btrfs_free_extent:3053: errno=-5 IO failure
Aug 10 21:33:11 DesktopRon kernel: BTRFS info (device sdb1: state EA): forced readonly
Aug 10 21:33:11 DesktopRon kernel: BTRFS error (device sdb1: state EA): failed to run delayed ref for logical 574197252096 num_bytes 16384 type 176 action 2 ref_mod 1: -5
Aug 10 21:33:11 DesktopRon kernel: BTRFS: error (device sdb1: state EA) in btrfs_run_delayed_refs:2127: errno=-5 IO failure
```

how do I repair this problem?
Thank you!

I'm using `Fedora 38`

Answer (score 0):

ok, I think I have figured out that my problem was caused by `syncthing` which is jhust a hunch I had, there's nothing logical I have in my hand that obviously pointed me towards it. I'm still wondering what the issue was caused by in detail - if someone can help me out, that would be great!